# docker: mount: creates intermediate folders as root instead of the hostuser

Tags: docker

CASE 1:

I am trying to mount a host folder `dir1` to `/dir1` inside docker

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -v "$(pwd)/dir1":"/dir1" \
some_image /bin/bash
```

I see the permissions inside docker as

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 hostuser users 4096 Apr 18 13:51 dir1
```

CASE 2:

Where as if i try to mount a nested folder, i see the parent folders are created with root user and the only the last directory has the host user permission

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -v "$(pwd)/dir1/dir2":"/dir1/dir2" \
some_image /bin/bash
```

here i see /dir1 permission inside docker as

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 18 13:51 dir1
```

and

here i see /dir1/dir2 permission inside docker as

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 hostuser users 4096 Apr 18 13:51 dir2
```

I am expecting both the `dir1` and `dir2` to have `hostuser users` permissions

How can i achieve this

**SOLUTION**

```
docker run --rm -it \
  -v "$(pwd)/dir1":"/dir1" \
  -v "$(pwd)/dir1/dir2":"/dir1/dir2" \
someimage /bin/bash
```

I have to mount the parent folder also then i can see its permission as hostusers

Answer (score 2):

The `dockerd` engine is running as root, it doesn't know anything about the user running the `docker` process, just like a web server doesn't know the user id of the user running the browser.

What controls the UID is whether you have setup user namespaces (off by default because of the way they break these bind mounts), and the user of the process running inside the container. If your container is running as root, it will create files as the root user, exactly the same as if you ran any root process on Linux.

To override the default user configured in the image, you can pass the `-u` flag:

```
docker run --rm -it \
  -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
  -v "$(pwd)/dir1":"/dir1" \
  some_image /bin/bash
```

However, realize that image creators expect their container to run with the uid they have configured, and there may be other changes to the image needed to support running the container as a different UID. I've often made images that handle this with a `fixperms` script from [my docker-base](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base) repo. I call that script as part of the entrypoint to modify the container UID to match the directory (volume mount) UID, and then run `gosu` to switch from running as root to running as that container user.

Also note that `dir1` should already exist on the host in advance. Otherwise, the docker engine has a feature where it will create the missing source folder for you, but doesn't know the permissions/ownership to give it, and just goes with the default root:root ownership. If docker didn't do that, the bind mount would fail, since Linux requires the bind mount source to already exist.

Exceptions to this are when the filesystem goes through some kind of intermediate layer, like NFS doing a squash, or Docker Desktop syncing the host directories with those of the embedded Linux VM.

Comment: Assume my host `uid:gid` are `1000:100` and also my dockerimage has a user same as `1000:100`. Now even i use `-u "1000:100"` it will create `dir1` as `root:root` and dir2 as `1000:100`

Comment: @Santhosh you need to create `dir1` in advance. The docker engine doesn't know what directory owner/permissions to setup for you, and it's a bit of a feature the directory gets created at all by docker, since a bind mount command fails when the source directory is missing in Linux.

Comment: added my solution in the question.

Comment: I think your comment answers the question. But the real answer is not tallking about this. can you replace the answer with this. So that i can click as answer